# How can I create a foreign key referring to primary keys across multiple tables with postgresql and .NET Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I create an API with .NET Core and I use Entity Framework.

How can I create a foreign key referring to primary keys across multiple tables with Postgresql and .NET Core?

In .NET core:

```
public class GeneralSetting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DefaultElement { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefaultElement")]
    public Access DefaultAccess { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefaultElement")]
    public Status DefaultStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefaultElement")]
    public Type DefaultType { get; set; }
}
```

ApiContext :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GeneralSetting>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("general_setting");
    entity.HasKey(t => t.Name);

    entity.Property(t => t.Name)
        .HasColumnName("name");

    entity.Property(t => t.DefaultElement)
        .HasColumnName("default_element")
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .IsRequired();

    entity.HasOne(t => t.DefaultType)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.DefaultElement);

    entity.HasOne(t => t.DefaultAccess)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.DefaultElement);

    entity.HasOne(t => t.DefaultStatus)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.DefaultElement);
});
```

I want to have someting like this :

Table **access** :

```
|  id  |  name |
+------+-------+
|  1   |  a1   |
|  2   |  a2   |
```

Table **type** :

```
|  id  |  name |
+------+-------+
|  1   |  t1   |
|  2   |  t2   |
```

Table **status** :

```
|  id  |  name |
+------+-------+
|  1   |  s1   |
|  2   |  s2   |
```

Table **general_setting** :

```
|  name   |  setting  |
+---------+-----------+
|  set1   |  a1       |
|  set2   |  t2       |
|  set3   |  s1       |
```

But when I want to create a row in table general_setting with my api, I get an internal server error.

Comment: Databases don't work this way; you'll need to use a trigger to enforce this relationship

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't know how to do it.

Comment: At a guess youre going to have to do this by mapping an inheritance tree where generalsetting is a base type and access/type/status is a derived type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance